# jQuery array start with the specific index and move preceding to the end of array

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexing, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using Fancybox jQuery plugin, which I call manually when the click event occurs. The problem I'm facing is when I'm using a group of images in order to be able to navigate between them using arrows. For this purpose all images in the group have the same 'rel' attribute. Everything seem to work fine with the below code, which I've managed to write, but the problem is with the first loaded image because even if I click the second image - the first one shows in the lightbox as that's the first index in the created array.

So my question is - how  can I rearrange the array so that the clicked item will become the first one and the preceding ones are moved to the end of array - basically moving items.

Example would be:

```
var thisArray = [ item-1, item-2, item-3 ];
var thisArray = [ item-2, item-3, item-1 ];
```

My code is as follow (I've also already have the 'currentIndex' variable, which returns the index of the clicked element:

```
lightbox : function(obj) {
    "use strict";
    obj.live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var thisObj = $(this);

        var thisOptions = {
            beforeLoad  : function() {
                $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            },
            afterClose  : function() {
                $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
            },              
            scrolling   : 'no',
            fitToView   : true,
            margin      : 0,
            padding     : 0,
            closeBtn    : false,
            closeClick  : true,
            arrows      : true,
            helpers     : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedIn  : 0,
                    speedOut : 300,
                    opacity  : 1,
                    css      : {
                        cursor : 'pointer',
                        'background-color' : '#000'
                    },
                    closeClick: true
                }
            }
        };

        var thisAttrRel = thisObj.attr('rel');
        if (thisAttrRel) {
            var thisObjs = $('a[rel='+thisAttrRel+']');
            if (thisObjs.length > 1) {
                var currentIndex = thisObjs.index(thisObj);
                var thisItems = [];
                jQuery.each(thisObjs, function() {
                    var thisHref = $(this).attr('href');
                    var thisTitle = $(this).attr('title');
                    thisItems.push({ 'href' : thisHref, 'title' : thisTitle });
                });
                jQuery.fancybox.open(thisItems, thisOptions);
            }
        } else {
            thisOptions.href = thisObj.attr('href'),
            jQuery.fancybox(thisOptions);
        }       

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - since I couldn't find the answer anywhere I've tried and managed to create a method to rearrange the array - here it is for those who also came across the same problem:

```
arrayReArrange : function(thisFirst, thisArray) {
    "use strict";
    if (thisFirst !== 0 && thisArray && thisArray.length > 0) {
        var thisNewArray = [];
        var i = 0;
        var thisIndex = 0;
        while (i < (thisArray.length + thisFirst)) {
            if (thisFirst === i) {
                thisNewArray.push(thisArray[thisIndex]);
            } else if (thisNewArray.length > 0) {
                thisNewArray.push(thisArray[thisIndex]);
            }
            if (thisIndex === (thisArray.length - 1)) {
                thisIndex = 0;
            } else {
                thisIndex++;
            }               
            i++;
        }
        return thisNewArray;
    } else {
        return thisArray;
    }
}
```

And now I can call it from within my lightbox() method:

```
lightbox : function(obj) {
    "use strict";
    obj.live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var thisObj = $(this);

        var thisOptions = {
            beforeLoad  : function() {
                $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            },
            afterClose  : function() {
                $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
            },              
            scrolling   : 'no',
            fitToView   : true,
            margin      : 0,
            padding     : 0,
            closeBtn    : false,
            closeClick  : true,
            arrows      : true,
            helpers     : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedIn  : 0,
                    speedOut : 300,
                    opacity  : 1,
                    css      : {
                        cursor : 'pointer',
                        'background-color' : '#000'
                    },
                    closeClick: true
                }
            }
        };

        var thisAttrRel = thisObj.attr('rel');
        if (thisAttrRel) {
            var thisObjs = $('a[rel='+thisAttrRel+']');
            if (thisObjs.length > 1) {                  
                var thisItems = [];
                jQuery.each(thisObjs, function() {
                    var thisHref = $(this).attr('href');
                    var thisTitle = $(this).attr('title');
                    thisItems.push({ 'href' : thisHref, 'title' : thisTitle });
                });
                var currentIndex = thisObjs.index(thisObj);
                thisItems = systemObject.arrayReArrange(currentIndex, thisItems);
                console.log(thisItems);
                jQuery.fancybox.open(thisItems, thisOptions);
            }
        } else {
            thisOptions.href = thisObj.attr('href'),
            jQuery.fancybox(thisOptions);
        }       

    });
}
```